# setTimeOut and typing effect

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm currently running into this issue, I would like to show a word slowly in this example I would like to show "Hello my name is..." but it should log like that :

"H" then 500 ms later
"He" then 500 ms later
"Hel" then...
"Hell" etc...

but all show instantly thanks for your time.

```js
    function type(string, length) {
        if(length < string.length+1) {
            console.log(string.slice(0, length), length);
            setTimeout(type(string, length+1), 500);
        }
    }
    
    type("hello my name is...", 1);
```

Comment: This is happening because instead of passing the function as a parameter, you're calling the function on the parameter's location.

Comment: `setTimeout(somefunction(),delay)` ***calls*** `somefunction()` and assigns its **return value** as the callback to be delayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because instead of passing the function as a parameter, you're calling the function on the parameter's location.

You can use `bind` to pass the function's reference with parameters. Like this:

```js
function type(string, length) {
        if(length < string.length+1) {
            console.log(string.slice(0, length), length);
            setTimeout(type.bind(null, string, length+1), 500);
        }
    }
    
    type("hello my name is...", 1);
```

Noticed the first parameter on `bind` is `null`. That's because the first parameter is the value of `this` inside the function. Since it's not used, you can use `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing the proper first argument to **[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)**. It takes a function ***reference*** as the first parameter, but you are passing a function ***invocation*** - - you are calling for `type` to be run immediately and the return vale from `type` (`undefined` in your case) is being passed to `setTimeout()`.

If you wrap your function invocation in a function declaration, the problem is solved.

```js
function type(string, length) {

    if(length < string.length+1) {
        console.log(string.slice(0, length), length);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){type(string, length+1)}, 500);
    }
}

type("hello my name is...", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks I see my mistake now !

Comment: @GeoffreyMigliacci You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark this answer as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.